# Creating an Age variable based on two Columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, lubridate

I am trying to create an age_at_enrollment variable, based on the start_date per individual (i.e. I want to know an individual's age, when they began their subsidized job).
Thus far, this is my code and it works:

```
teachers_subsidy4 = teachers_subsidy3 %>% mutate(age_at_enrollment = as.Date(start_date)-as.Date(birth_date))

head(teachers_subsidy4)
```

However, the variable is shown as the number of days, rather than years. Any thoughts on how to display the age in terms of years?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
teachers_subsidy4 = teachers_subsidy3 
%>% mutate(age_at_enrollment = (as.Date(start_date)-as.Date(birth_date))/365.25)

head(teachers_subsidy4)
```